# Passing a varable from a JFrame to another

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

I want to pass a variable from a JFrame to another when I'm pressing the `btnCalculeaza` button.

Here is my code:

```
JButton btnCalculeaza = new JButton("Calculeaza");
        btnCalculeaza.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 int algad = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                 int analiza = Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
                 int be = Integer.parseInt(textField_2.getText());
                 int depcom = Integer.parseInt(textField_3.getText());
                 int engleza1 = Integer.parseInt(textField_4.getText());
                 int engleza2= Integer.parseInt(textField_5.getText());
                 int fizica= Integer.parseInt(textField_6.getText());
                 int grafica= Integer.parseInt(textField_7.getText());
                 int informatica= Integer.parseInt(textField_8.getText());
                 int matematici= Integer.parseInt(textField_9.getText());
                 int programare1= Integer.parseInt(textField_10.getText());
                 int programare2= Integer.parseInt(textField_11.getText());
                 int tpsm= Integer.parseInt(textField_12.getText());
                double nota1;

            nota1=(7*algad+analiza*6.0+7*be+3*depcom+2*engleza1+2*engleza2+fizica*7+grafica*3+informatica*4+matematici*6+programare1*5+programare2*4+tpsm*4)/60;
                System.out.println(nota1);
                new Anul2(nota1).setVisible(true);
                Anul2 anul2 =new Anul2();
                anul2.setVisible(true);
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });
```

And the second `JFrame`:

```
public class Anul2 extends JFrame {

    private double nota1;
    public Anul2(double nota1) {
        this.nota1 = nota1;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Anul2 frame = new Anul2();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Anul2() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 527, 407);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        JLabel lblMediaGeneralaPana = new JLabel("Media generala pana acum:");
        lblMediaGeneralaPana.setBounds(12, 331, 160, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblMediaGeneralaPana);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
        lblNewLabel.setText(Double.toString(nota1));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(171, 331, 56, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
    }
}
```

I would like to pass the `nota1` variable to the second `JFrame`(called `Anul2`) and then I want to convert it to a `JLabel`

Comment: Add `this()` to your `public Anul2(double nota1) {` constructor, this way it will construct the UI as part of it's work

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Beyond that, for naming: there is no point in naming variables t_1, t_2, ... and so on. *Either* use an array then (so you can loop over those things), OR use a meaningful name, such as `tf_algad`... and so on. But mentally mapping "tf1" is "algad" ... that is not a pattern that scales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your real problem is that your mixing up **responsibilities** in your code.

You should fully separate your data processing form your UI stuff.

Meaning: you have a local variable

```
nota1=(7*algad+analiza*6.0+7*be+3*depcom+2*engleza1+2*engleza2+fizica*7+grafica*3+informatica*4+matematici*6+programare1*5+programare2*4+tpsm*4)/60;
```

and its extremely complicated computation within an action listener. Such things don't belong there.

Instead, you should have a distinct class that *only* holds all the parameters required for that computation. And then, that class has probably a method `computeNota()`.

Now: in your action listener, you create an object of that class, and then you could pass on that object to new JFRame for example.

Decouple the processing of your data from *showing* it to the user!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways,

1. Pass a reference of the first JFrame to the second JFrame Constructor.
2. Use getFrames() method along with getDeclaredFields() to get the nota1 variable value.

Comment: You mean `getDeclaredFields()` together with reflection? If so: really bad advice.